# Is there a way to duplicate a google sheet with zapier and preserve the sharing permissons?

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

When using the zap to "duplicate a google sheet" the sharing settings revert to private regardless of the source sheet's settings.  I'd like it to preserve the original settings of the source sheet, ie so that the copy can be shared.

Or alternately, is there a way to set up a zap that changes sharing settings afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive integration has an Add File Sharing Preference. You could add an extra step to the zap and add the sharing preference there. Note that that action doesn't *change* sharing preferences, it just adds to the existing ones.

If you want to submit a feature request for the Google Sheets action to contain that functionality you can do that [here](https://zapier.com/app/get-help).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Not sure why this was so hard to find!